# Was the act of deletion for a unlikely Racist slur itself also an act of unintentional racism?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

***Note:*** the links below won't work for users without enough reputation points to read deleted answers.  I've used '___' to obscure a term the moderator believes to be a slur.

[*Phillip*'s comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31968/why-is-president-trump-ending-affirmative-action-in-college-admissions-so-contro#comment119006_31969) provides a rationale for deleting [*guest271314* answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/31970/8647) to [Why is President Trump ending affirmative action in college admissions so controversial?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31968/why-is-president-trump-ending-affirmative-action-in-college-admissions-so-contro):

> Racist slurs like "Ne__o" and "black students suckle on the teat of western academia" are not tolerated on the Stack Exchange network.

Surely most everyone must agree that racist slurs, (or any slurs for that matter), should have no place here, and would applaud his (or anyone's) intention to expunge any and all such slurs.

But *Phillip* seems to regard "Ne___o" as a racist slur, rather than as a once formal neutral standard but now obsolescent political term.

He also seems to think comparing Western Academia to a teat should be considered either as a slur or as bad as one.  The comparison is self-deprecating academic irony, and a riff of [*Alma Mater*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alma_mater).

I would assume that *guest271314* is a black person, (for so says the introduction to his deleted answer), and given the general tenor of *guest271314*'s posts so far, is very probably not a white-supremacist racist prone to racial slurs.

(The answer by *guest271314* seems to have argued that the Academic version of *'50s* US School Desegregation resulted in a general overvaluation of blander mainstream scholarship and with it a corresponding but unmerited deprecation of segregated scholarship.)

This particular deletion seems incorrect.

Comment: I can't speak for Phillip, but If I had to handle that flag, I would be very nervous of getting backlash If I declined the flag declaring that "negro" is not a racial slur, or declaring that `black students off of the teat of western academia` is not a racist comment.  Even if the context suggests otherwise.

Comment: Also, that answer was barely even tangentially related to the question(which was about affirmative action in colleges).  When a user posts an answer to soapbox about a mostly unrelated topic, such a post will usually get deleted if flagged, and that's what this post was doing.

Comment: Why does the word in question being "once formal neutral standard but now obsolescent political term" preclude it from being a racial slur in 2018?

Comment: @SamIam, Let's stay on topic.  *Phillip*'s stated reason for deletion was racism, not relevance.

Comment: @AzorAhai, The word *"neutral"* precludes it from being a racial slur, as well its longstanding use by the [UNCF](http://www.uncf.org/) and in the works of now-classic author-reformers such as *MLK*, *W. E. B. Du Bois*, and *Frederick Douglass*.

Comment: @agc "*once* formal neutral standard" Just because you consider something to have been "neutral" at one point doesn't mean everyone considers it to be neutral still ... and as you point out, those are classic authors, who died 50+ years ago.  Besides the note about the UNCF, you haven't made a convincing case that "negro" is obvioulsy no longer a slur.

Comment: @AzorAhai, Classic authors never really die, but live on in spirit through their works, through their readers.  Unless every living reader dies, and every last copy and quote and derivative work is obliterated, (so long as one copy of one book remained, a thousand years later that dormant seed might flourish again), classics survive the fashionable generational migrations of human Buffalo herds.

Comment: @agc While poetic, that means nothing in this context.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312290/answer-deleted-and-account-suspended-for-using-the-term-negro-in-an-answer-fact

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, It's a *404*.  Was that question itself related, or is it the fact that it was deleted at all that makes it interesting?

Comment: The user in question had made a post contesting their suspension, which I linked above. It's now deleted.

Comment: Just FYI: guest has now made two wildly off-topic posts on Meta Stack Exchange, one written in the third person, championing the use of the term negro here via a bunch of irrelevant references. Assuming good faith at the outset is useful, but at this point I wouldn't recommend extending it further.

Comment: @agc - Having looked at the context of what they wrote, I agree that they're very likely not a white supremacist of any stripe. But I think it's possible that they have some black nationalist leanings (if you look at the chat discussion under the question, they spend a lot of time defending black nationalist ideas, particularly from the Nation of Islam). Not a good enough reason to delete the comment, I agree, but something to be aware of.

Comment: The context in which they characterize black students as "sucking at the teat of Western academia" clearly has nothing of anti-black sentiment. But it does seem contemptuous of the direction mainstream anti-racist thought and activism have gone (thus the use of an old-fashioned term), and of black people whom the author seems to *view* as trying too hard to assimilate, for instance black Greek organizations and upper-class black people (you can see that in their answer below). They're not simply talking about Ben Carson and Kanye there, I think.

Comment: It's tricky, because I feel that the answer in question probably contributed a useful opinion to the discussion - I'm generally not a big deletion fan, particularly deletion over political opinions on a politics website. I prefer downvotes, because they exoress disapproval rather than saying that a view has no place here . But at the same time, I think there's no point in not asserting that the poster has been expousing, and defending some pretty unpleasant things.

Comment: @Obie2.0, I agree that accidentally upgrading a downvote to a deletion is terrible policy and has a chilling effect.  Re *"...mainstream anti-racist thought..."*:  well, *guest271314*'s contention is that via a semantic shell game the mainstream is not truly as *anti* as it purports to be, and this view, right or wrong, and relative to the plurality of strong opinions found on *Politics.SE*, does not seem particularly radical, and we've nobody else giving that perspective, so it helps provide us a certain balance.

Comment: @agc - Mmmm. Goodness knows we have some people expressing some unpleasant opinions (I've seen some definite white supremacist answers here, for instance, including some regular users). But (radical or not), they're saying some pretty unpleasant things (did you read their defense of Wallace Fard Muhammed in chat?)

Comment: @Obie2.0, If some bit of data seems relevant, URLs are preferable to allusions.  In any case the errors of those with strong opinions, while regrettable, are less useful to us than those instances in which they seem nearer to truth than others.     We value [Kepler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Kepler) for his useful work, which we don't trash just because he was nutty about music and argued at great length about why the [planet Mars was a tenor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonices_Mundi#Content).

Comment: @agc - In the case of a person's political theory, understanding where they're coming from is important. [Here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80153/discussion-on-answer-by-guest271314-is-there-any-difference-between-black-suprem) you go.

Comment: While they might have a point about (say) some of the unintended effects of anti-segregation policies, their defense of the Nation of Islam and Louis Farrakhan, the denial that they have a black nationalist ideology (and indeed, basically stating that black nationalists can't exist) raises a major red flag with me. The NoL is, unfortunately, anti-white, anti-Jewish, anti-gay, and historically anti-Hindu. They're classified as a black nationalist group by the SPLC and others. Not to mention the characterization of upper-class black people and black Greek organizations as sell-outs.

Comment: Not to mention that the NoL is now affiliated with the exploitative religion of Scientology, kind of, with Farrakhan magnanimously saying that if you studies Scientology, "you can still be a Christian; you just won't be a devil Christian. You'll still be a Jew, but you won't be a satanic Jew." So, yeah. Defending the Nation of Islam, and Farrakhan and Fard Muhammad, dismissing their harsh words as mere allegory, insisting that they are not black nationalists (or that it doesn't matter, because on the *whole*,  white organizations are much more dominant) - major red flag.

Comment: Is it as bad as rs.29 defending white supremacy and insisting that it be called white nationalism, that it seeks only to preserve European values, that "the globalists" want you to call it that, that acknowledging white supremacy means you want to exterminate white people, thus feeding into an ideology that's causing a lot more harm in the world today than the Nation of Islam can dream of doing? Not even close. But it's very negative nonetheless.

Comment: @Obie2.0, Reviewing that thread, it's a semantic argument regarding the term *"supremacy"*, with little to say about your present streak of inferential constructions.  For political questions about those sects, please post some other question.

Comment: @agc - That semantic argument was there, sure (and to be fair, "black nationalism" is usually preferred as more accurate than "black supremacism") but it was only part of what they said. If you won't see it, you won't see it.

Comment: Stating that a group's prejudiced ideology is merely an allegory doesn't strike you as apology for the group? It's good to give the benefit of the doubt, but I think you are taking it too far here.

Comment: @Looking at their other answers, they do have a lot of good answers about various issues. That doesn't give one a pass on apology for a group like NoI. But in case I'm being too quick to leap to judgment, maybe I should ask them what they think specifically.

Comment: @Obie2.0, Like yourself *guest271314* is not a member of that sect, nor an expert on it.  His interpretation of its mythology was merely somewhat less literal than yours.

Comment: @agc - Are you sure? I'm not a member nor an expert to be sure, but guest271314 could surely be either, or both? Anyway, I don't want to be unfair and accuse someone of supporting a nasty group without being certain, so I asked them more specifically in chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80484/discussion-between-agc-and-obie-2-0).

Comment: @agc https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-question-ban-for-user-guest271314

Comment: @Obie2.0 Since you appear to be fixated on the Nation of Islam, if (**have**) you asked that organization specifically _"Is the Nation of Islam a 'black supremacist' organization?"_ and the organizations' official reply was _"No"_, would you accept that reply as factual and end your inquiry? The point being have you actually asked the organization that question? And whatever the organizations' answer is, will that change _your_ predisposed notion of the organization being a so-called "black supremacist" organization? Your opinion suggests that your view of the Nation of Islam is static, fixed.

Comment: @guest271314 - Trump tried asking Putin whether he had interfered in US elections. I'm sure that the NoI's denial would be just as "extremely strong" as Putin's, and nearly as trustworthy. But given your responses to my questions, not only not recognizing the NoI's rhetoric and views against Jews and white people (and offering vague support for the former), calling being LBGT a lifestyle, and otherwise engaging apologetics, I've lost all confidence in your good faith in this matter.

Comment: @Obie2.0 "confidence" and "faith" are irrelevant to facts. There is no evidence that "Putin" "interfered in US elections". You are not interested in facts, but rather, "confidence" and "faith". As suspected, your views are fixed, making your entire inquiry as to the Nation of Islam subjective and incapable of being otherwise. None of what you mention have anything to do with "black supremacism" and the Nation of Islam because you have failed to ask the organization your questions.

Comment: @guest271314 - Nice, apology for Putin too, naturally.

Comment: @Obie2.0 There are no apologies for anyone. Have no horse in the race either way. Do not fly any of the flags which you are fixated on. Your analysis is simply flawed.

Comment: The Republican Party wouldn't call itself anti-gay if you asked them - they're merely defending "freedom of religion. "Contrary to what you believe, many white supremacist groups will not tell you that that's what they are, insisting that they are merely "white nationalists" or "alt-right." President Trump won't admit that his travel order is a Muslim ban. Do you believe all these people, too?

Comment: @Obie2.0  If the group says they are "Republican Party", "white nationals", or "alt-right", then that is what they are. There are several perspectives which could be considered; i.e.g., 1) "they are all the same"; 2) "all politics is local: meet the actual people". The "they are all the same" approach is static: one basket; the "all politics is local: meet the actual people" approach is dynamic. There is hazard in pronouncing "pro-0" and "anti-1"; "pro-0" can be a mask for self-preservation or aggrandizement; unexpected diplomatic relations and alliances with "anti-1" based on common interests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No individual person or group owns or controls the meaning of the word Negro. As with any word within the equivocal language english, there can be more than a single definition applied to the term.

It is preposterous for anyone on a political board to actually state that Negro is a "Racial slurs"; such a statement is incredibly narrow minded and out of touch with the reality of Negro culture, history, literature and politics in the United States

- [Universal Negro Improvement Association and African Communities
  League](https://www.theunia-acl.com/)
- [United Negro College Fund](https://uncf.org/)
- [The Awakening of the Negro](https://www.theatlantic.com/past/docs/unbound/flashbks/blacked/washaw.htm)
- [Strivings of the Negro People](https://www.theatlantic.com/past/docs/unbound/flashbks/black/dubstriv.htm)
- [The Case of the Negro](https://www.theatlantic.com/past/docs/unbound/flashbks/black/washbh.htm)
- [Negro Leagues Legacy](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/history/mlb_negro_leagues.jsp)
- [Negro Leagues Team Histories by MLB.com](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/history/mlb_negro_leagues_teams.jsp)
- > ["Letter from a Birmingham Jail [King, Jr.]"](https://www.africa.upenn.edu/Articles_Gen/Letter_Birmingham.html) 
  >   16 April 1963 My
  >   Dear Fellow Clergymen:
  >
  > ...
  >
  > You deplore the demonstrations taking place in Birmingham. But your
  >   statement, I am sorry to say, fails to express a similar concern for
  >   the conditions that brought about the demonstrations. I am sure that
  >   none of you would want to rest content with the superficial kind of
  >   social analysis that deals merely with effects and does not grapple
  >   with underlying causes. It is unfortunate that demonstrations are
  >   taking place in Birmingham, but it is even more unfortunate that the
  >   city's white power structure left the Negro community with no
  >   alternative.
  >
  > In any nonviolent campaign there are four basic steps: collection of
  >   the facts to determine whether injustices exist; negotiation; self
  >   purification; and direct action. We have gone through all these steps
  >   in Birmingham. There can be no gainsaying the fact that racial
  >   injustice engulfs this community. Birmingham is probably the most
  >   thoroughly segregated city in the United States. Its ugly record of
  >   brutality is widely known. Negroes have experienced grossly unjust
  >   treatment in the courts. There have been more unsolved bombings of
  >   Negro homes and churches in Birmingham than in any other city in the
  >   nation. These are the hard, brutal facts of the case. On the basis of
  >   these conditions, Negro leaders sought to negotiate with the city
  >   fathers. But the latter consistently refused to engage in good faith
  >   negotiation.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > We know through painful experience that freedom is never voluntarily
  >   given by the oppressor; it must be demanded by the oppressed. Frankly,
  >   I have yet to engage in a direct action campaign that was "well timed"
  >   in the view of those who have not suffered unduly from the disease of
  >   segregation. For years now I have heard the word "Wait!" It rings in
  >   the ear of every Negro with piercing familiarity. This "Wait" has
  >   almost always meant "Never." We must come to see, with one of our
  >   distinguished jurists, that "justice too long delayed is justice
  >   denied."
  >
  > We have waited for more than 340 years for our constitutional and God
  >   given rights. The nations of Asia and Africa are moving with jetlike
  >   speed toward gaining political independence, but we still creep at
  >   horse and buggy pace toward gaining a cup of coffee at a lunch
  >   counter. Perhaps it is easy for those who have never felt the stinging
  >   darts of segregation to say, "Wait." But when you have seen vicious
  >   mobs lynch your mothers and fathers at will and drown your sisters and
  >   brothers at whim; when you have seen hate filled policemen curse, kick
  >   and even kill your black brothers and sisters; when you see the vast
  >   majority of your twenty million Negro brothers smothering in an
  >   airtight cage of poverty in the midst of an affluent society; when you
  >   suddenly find your tongue twisted and your speech stammering as you
  >   seek to explain to your six year old daughter why she can't go to the
  >   public amusement park that has just been advertised on television, and
  >   see tears welling up in her eyes when she is told that Funtown is
  >   closed to colored children, and see ominous clouds of inferiority
  >   beginning to form in her little mental sky, and see her beginning to
  >   distort her personality by developing an unconscious bitterness toward
  >   white people; when you have to concoct an answer for a five year old
  >   son who is asking: "Daddy, why do white people treat colored people so
  >   mean?"; when you take a cross county drive and find it necessary to
  >   sleep night after night in the uncomfortable corners of your
  >   automobile because no motel will accept you; when you are humiliated
  >   day in and day out by nagging signs reading "white" and "colored";
  >   when your first name becomes "nigger," your middle name becomes "boy"
  >   (however old you are) and your last name becomes "John," and your wife
  >   and mother are never given the respected title "Mrs."; when you are
  >   harried by day and haunted by night by the fact that you are a Negro,
  >   living constantly at tiptoe stance, never quite knowing what to expect
  >   next, and are plagued with inner fears and outer resentments; when you
  >   are forever fighting a degenerating sense of "nobodiness"--then you
  >   will understand why we find it difficult to wait. There comes a time
  >   when the cup of endurance runs over, and men are no longer willing to
  >   be plunged into the abyss of despair. I hope, sirs, you can understand
  >   our legitimate and unavoidable impatience. You express a great deal of
  >   anxiety over our willingness to break laws. This is certainly a
  >   legitimate concern. Since we so diligently urge people to obey the
  >   Supreme Court's decision of 1954 outlawing segregation in the public
  >   schools, at first glance it may seem rather paradoxical for us
  >   consciously to break laws. One may well ask: "How can you advocate
  >   breaking some laws and obeying others?" The answer lies in the fact
  >   that there are two types of laws: just and unjust. I would be the
  >   first to advocate obeying just laws. One has not only a legal but a
  >   moral responsibility to obey just laws. Conversely, one has a moral
  >   responsibility to disobey unjust laws. I would agree with St.
  >   Augustine that "an unjust law is no law at all."
  >
  > ...
  >
  > Let us consider a more concrete example of just and unjust laws. An
  >   unjust law is a code that a numerical or power majority group compels
  >   a minority group to obey but does not make binding on itself. This is
  >   difference made legal. By the same token, a just law is a code that a
  >   majority compels a minority to follow and that it is willing to follow
  >   itself. This is sameness made legal. Let me give another explanation.
  >   A law is unjust if it is inflicted on a minority that, as a result of
  >   being denied the right to vote, had no part in enacting or devising
  >   the law. Who can say that the legislature of Alabama which set up that
  >   state's segregation laws was democratically elected? Throughout
  >   Alabama all sorts of devious methods are used to prevent Negroes from
  >   becoming registered voters, and there are some counties in which, even
  >   though Negroes constitute a majority of the population, not a single
  >   Negro is registered. Can any law enacted under such circumstances be
  >   considered democratically structured?
  >
  > ...
  >
  > You speak of our activity in Birmingham as extreme. At first I was
  >   rather disappointed that fellow clergymen would see my nonviolent
  >   efforts as those of an extremist. I began thinking about the fact that
  >   I stand in the middle of two opposing forces in the Negro community.
  >   One is a force of complacency, made up in part of Negroes who, as a
  >   result of long years of oppression, are so drained of self respect and
  >   a sense of "somebodiness" that they have adjusted to segregation; and
  >   in part of a few middle-class Negroes who, because of a degree of
  >   academic and economic security and because in some ways they profit by
  >   segregation, have become insensitive to the problems of the masses.
  >   The other force is one of bitterness and hatred, and it comes
  >   perilously close to advocating violence. It is expressed in the
  >   various black nationalist groups that are springing up across the
  >   nation, the largest and best known being Elijah Muhammad's Muslim
  >   movement. Nourished by the Negro's frustration over the continued
  >   existence of racial discrimination, this movement is made up of people
  >   who have lost faith in America, who have absolutely repudiated
  >   Christianity, and who have concluded that the white man is an
  >   incorrigible "devil."
  >
  > I have tried to stand between these two forces, saying that we need
  >   emulate neither the "do nothingism" of the complacent nor the hatred
  >   and despair of the black nationalist. For there is the more excellent
  >   way of love and nonviolent protest. I am grateful to God that, through
  >   the influence of the Negro church, the way of nonviolence became an
  >   integral part of our struggle. If this philosophy had not emerged, by
  >   now many streets of the South would, I am convinced, be flowing with
  >   blood. And I am further convinced that if our white brothers dismiss
  >   as "rabble rousers" and "outside agitators" those of us who employ
  >   nonviolent direct action, and if they refuse to support our nonviolent
  >   efforts, millions of Negroes will, out of frustration and despair,
  >   seek solace and security in black nationalist ideologies--a
  >   development that would inevitably lead to a frightening racial
  >   nightmare.
  >
  > Oppressed people cannot remain oppressed forever. The yearning for
  >   freedom eventually manifests itself, and that is what has happened to
  >   the American Negro. Something within has reminded him of his
  >   birthright of freedom, and something without has reminded him that it
  >   can be gained. Consciously or unconsciously, he has been caught up by
  >   the Zeitgeist, and with his black brothers of Africa and his brown and
  >   yellow brothers of Asia, South America and the Caribbean, the United
  >   States Negro is moving with a sense of great urgency toward the
  >   promised land of racial justice. If one recognizes this vital urge
  >   that has engulfed the Negro community, one should readily understand
  >   why public demonstrations are taking place. The Negro has many pent up
  >   resentments and latent frustrations, and he must release them. So let
  >   him march; let him make prayer pilgrimages to the city hall; let him
  >   go on freedom rides -and try to understand why he must do so. If his
  >   repressed emotions are not released in nonviolent ways, they will seek
  >   expression through violence; this is not a threat but a fact of
  >   history. So I have not said to my people: "Get rid of your
  >   discontent." Rather, I have tried to say that this normal and healthy
  >   discontent can be channeled into the creative outlet of nonviolent
  >   direct action. And now this approach is being termed extremist. But
  >   though I was initially disappointed at being categorized as an
  >   extremist, as I continued to think about the matter I gradually gained
  >   a measure of satisfaction from the label. Was not Jesus an extremist
  >   for love: "Love your enemies, bless them that curse you, do good to
  >   them that hate you, and pray for them which despitefully use you, and
  >   persecute you." Was not Amos an extremist for justice: "Let justice
  >   roll down like waters and righteousness like an ever flowing stream."
  >   Was not Paul an extremist for the Christian gospel: "I bear in my body
  >   the marks of the Lord Jesus." Was not Martin Luther an extremist:
  >   "Here I stand; I cannot do otherwise, so help me God." And John
  >   Bunyan: "I will stay in jail to the end of my days before I make a
  >   butchery of my conscience." And Abraham Lincoln: "This nation cannot
  >   survive half slave and half free." And Thomas Jefferson: "We hold
  >   these truths to be self evident, that all men are created equal . . ."
  >   So the question is not whether we will be extremists, but what kind of
  >   extremists we will be. Will we be extremists for hate or for love?
  >   Will we be extremists for the preservation of injustice or for the
  >   extension of justice? In that dramatic scene on Calvary's hill three
  >   men were crucified. We must never forget that all three were crucified
  >   for the same crime--the crime of extremism. Two were extremists for
  >   immorality, and thus fell below their environment. The other, Jesus
  >   Christ, was an extremist for love, truth and goodness, and thereby
  >   rose above his environment. Perhaps the South, the nation and the
  >   world are in dire need of creative extremists.

It is very unlikely that the culture of censorship at SE has dramatically changed within the span of this users' 7 day account suspension for previously answering this question and being censored by Politics SE moderator - twice. It is more than likely that the fervor for censorship has, if anything, increased, during that 7 day span.

The answer critics will undoubtedly ask: "How is the above paragraph related to the question?"

The answer to the house answer critics is that there is controversy related to every political decision. The decision by SE to delete this users' valid answers and suspend this users' account for using the word Negro within answers was a political decision by SE moderators and the organization itself, the evidence points to the ignorance of the individuals whom had the audacity to assert that upvote

> Racist slurs like "Negro" and "black students suckle on the teat of
>   western academia" are not tolerated on the Stack Exchange network..

when, in fact, the U.S. Government provides guidance for Federal agencies as to the fact of Negro people actually self-identifying as Negro at

[Revisions to the Standards for the Classification of Federal Data on Race and Ethnicity, Executive Office of the President, Office of Management and Budget, Washington, D.C. 20503](https://www.whitehouse.gov/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Revisions-to-the-Standards-for-the-Classification-of-Federal-Data-on-Race-and-Ethnicity-October30-1997.pdf)

> **(13) OMB accepts the following recommendations concerning the term or terms to be used for the name of the Black category:**
>  The name
>   of the Black category should be changed to "Black or African
>   American."
>
> The category definition should remain unchanged.
>
> Additional terms, such as Haitian or Negro, can be used if desired.

Thus, SE is technically potentially violating Federal regulations by attempting to censor an individual from self-identifying as Negro. Ironic, though possibly not ironic, at a question dealing with "scrap" of "affirmative action" policies by the U.S.

As to the concept of "black students suckle on the teat of western academia", that is a fact for groups such as [Sigma Pi Phi Fraternity](https://www.sigmapiphi.org/home/) also known as [the Boulé](https://www.sigmapiphi.org/home/history-of-the-boule.php), who adopt a Greek identity in colleges, rather than an African one. In effect, being a guard  for western academia against Negro/Black/African academia for their own political advantages within western academia and institutions, as is evident by their seal and description of themselves; the Boule thrive on suckling at the teat of western academia for nourishment, e.g., almer mater ("nourishing/kind" "mother"), both economically and politically

> [image]
>
> Sigma Pi Phi fraternity was formed in 1904 in Philadelphia,
>   Pennsylvania by a group of six African American professional men.  The
>   fraternity founders included; Henry McKee Minton, Dr. Algernon B.
>   Jackson, Dr. Edwin C. Howard, Dr. Richard J. Warrick, Robert J. Abele,
>   and Eugene T. Hinson.
>
> The fraternity was established so that educated African American men,
>   who were accomplished in their professions, could have a social,
>   spiritual and communial gathering space.  Within the group, members
>   are referred to as arcons and wives as archousai.
>
> The group's second member Boule "Beta Boule" was formed in 1907 in
>   Chicago followed by it's third member Boule in Baltimore in 1908. The
>   organization gradually became nationwide and has included many
>   prominent men including Martin Luther King, Jr. WEB Dubois, Arthur
>   Ashe, Ron Brown, Earl Graves of Black Enterprise Magazine, and John
>   Johnson of Ebony Magazine. Most prominent African Americans are
>   members including college presidents, congressmen, cabinet members,
>   and nationally prominent figures.  The fraternity is currently
>   comprised of 112 member Boules or chapters.
>
> The fraternity is often referred to as the Boule, which in fraternity
>   parlance means "a council of noblemen".
>
> The meaning of the words Sigma Pi Phi, the titles given to its members
>   and their wives, its officers and the names of its local units are
>   derived from Greek history and tradition as well.

In [Charles H. Wesley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_H._Wesley)'s *History of Sigma Pi Phi, First of the Negro-American Greek-letter Fraternities* at page 28:

> "[Minton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_McKee_Minton) wanted to create an organization which would partake in
>   the tenants (basis, or root) of Skull & Bones at Yale."

what some would refer "American Black Upper Class", others sell-outs, or worse.

Controversy cannot be avoided within the realm of politics, so-called "affirmative action" is no exception.

The answer should not have been deleted and this user account should not have been suspended.

Comment: Possible typo: _"would partake in the ten**an**ts"_, shouldn't this be *tenets*?

Comment: Also, this answer is excellent, but if possible please spell out a little bit more, (unless you're judiciously refraining from doing so, for understandable reasons), whether or not the deletion for a claimed slur was racist, and specifically in what sense, (*i.e.* institutional, personal, accidental, procedural absurdity, *de facto*, or something else), and whether it was intentional, well meaning, oblivious, or something else, or all of those at once...

Comment: @agc The deletion is founded in institutional racism and is intentional.

Answer (score 4):

#### Allowable words

One might guess that Philipp is white.  As far as I know, he (gender inferred from name) is from Germany, which has a small minority population.  He probably speaks English as a second language.

It is quite possible that he is not familiar with the difference between the words (at least one of which can be offensive, so read behind the spoiler tag at your own risk)

> Negro and nigger.

These words share a lot, four letters out of five or six.

There was a time when the first word was mainstream, the way that African-American is today.  For example, see [this organization](https://www.uncf.org/), which is run by and for African-Americans.

Of course, even given all that, it's hard for a white person to say that a particular word is all right over a black person's objection.  That the word was being used by a black person doesn't fix it.

#### The second answer

That said, I would tend to agree that the second posting of the answer, which started

> Don't ask about black people if you do not want answers from black people. Or, specify at the question that you only want answers from white people.

was overly hostile and perhaps misdirected.  I would be fine with deleting that based on the existence of the first answer, the hostile tone, and its misdirection to be justified.

Why misdirected?  Because it seems far more likely that the kind of person complaining about "negro" and "black students suckle on the teat of western academia" is either black or claiming that it would be offensive to black people.  And it seems unlikely that Philipp just happened to pick that answer to review.  It seems more likely that there was a flag.

Deleting the second posting of the answer was correct in my mind, even if the first deletion was not.  That's not how we resolve things here.  The correct way to get the answer restored is a meta question.

#### Selective enforcement

There is also a bit of a problem with allowing certain language by black people and not white people.  For one thing, we don't know who is black and who is white here.  If a white supremacist came here and posted about the difficulty of being black in the US, we can't really tell the difference from a black person doing the same thing.

Beyond that, even if we could prove blackness, it sets a bad precedent to allow one person to use language that we would not accept from another person.  Because then when someone else uses the same language, how do we say that it is now off limits?  We should have one standard for posts, not a different standard for each demographic group.

There may be some reason for an exception in certain cases because it is clearly necessary.  For example, the text that I put behind spoiler tags is important to the post.  Without it, I could just as well be talking about nitro and mentor.

At least the first particular word choice was not necessary.  Either black or African-American could be substituted for the one word without loss of understandability.

The phrase

> black students suckle on the teat of western academia

is harder to replace, as it carried actual meaning and many replacements would be offensive because of that meaning.

#### Authenticity

From a [comment](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3468/was-the-act-of-deletion-for-a-unlikely-racist-slur-itself-also-an-act-of-uninten?cb=1#comment7850_3468):

> It's possible that it was a non-black troll pretending to be black, but I think that the point of view is one actually held by the poster, because it's too weird to fake.

This point of view is more mainstream than it might first seem.  This is essentially the [Malcolm X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_X) view.  Malcolm X wasn't bothered by the concept of "separate but equal" but by the implementation.  He argued that it was not in fact equal, only separate.  He would have maintained the separation, but in return he wanted a real separation.  Black people would have their own place to live under their own laws and would not be subject to white law.  Something more like Native American reservations.  From the Wikipedia link:

> While the civil rights movement fought against racial segregation, Malcolm X advocated the complete separation of African Americans from whites. He proposed that African Americans should return to Africa and that, in the interim, a separate country for black people in America should be created.

It is possible that his views had mellowed later in life, when he was using the name el-Hajj Malik el-Shabazz.

It remains possible that this was a fake, a white supremacist or a Russian rabble rouser pretending to be a black separatist.  But it's also possible that this was just what it seemed, a post by a black person with heterodox/non-stereotypical views.

#### Whitesplainin'

I'm a bit troubled by

> (The answer by guest271314 seems to have argued that the Academic version of '50s US School Desegregation resulted in a general overvaluation of blander mainstream scholarship and with it a corresponding but unmerited deprecation of segregated scholarship.)

This seems to be a whitewash (see what I did there?) of the original post, which argued that school desegregation led to black children being predominantly taught by white teachers.  This increases alienation, as it produces weird white explanations like "blander mainstream scholarship" that seem to miss the point.

I don't want to get too much into that, as two white people arguing over what a black person meant is itself a microaggression.  Presumably the black person is better capable of clarifying what was meant than we are.  But until that, I didn't want to leave so egregious a rewriting unchallenged.

Original, potentially offensive, first paragraph for those who want to consider for themselves whose interpretation is closer:

> Some black people consider *Brown v. Board of Education of Topeka*, 347 U.S. 483 (1954) to be the worst decision as to Negro education that ever occurred, the reason being that Negro children would no longer being educated by Negro teachers from a Negro perspective, but would instead by educated by white teachers from a white perspective.

Comment: Re *"two white people arguing over what a black person meant is itself a microagression"*: such sweeping criteria would seem to include the whole of [Religious Studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_studies), and much of [Anthropology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthropology) , to say nothing of  translation...

Comment: BTW, I prefer *"blander mainstream scholarship"* in place of say, "white teachers from a white perspective", because:  scholarship is a less narrow term than teaching, (so much of what's taught in schools is indirect, osmotic and banally procedural), and an institution's per-capita proportion of melanin per teacher is far less important than its erroneously partisan homogeneity.  Just imagine two courses in legal ethics, one taught by Clarence Thomas and the other by Thurgood Marshall, then imagine both becoming take-charge college presidents reforming their universities as they best see fit.

Comment: In anthropology and religious studies, the (possibly black) person is long dead and unable to make her or his point clear.  Hopefully that doesn't apply in this case.  A ban seems much more likely to be preventing clarification.

Comment: I don't read scholarship as being the important aspect.  The important aspect is that a black child with black teachers has many role models who share that particular portion of their nature.  I'm not sure that it's better to have only black role models, but I'm not sure that it's worse either.  It may be better because the different cultural referents of the white teacher may serve to alienate the black child.  It's unproven which viewpoint is right and which wrong.  As such, I would rather not choose between them as yet and would prefer to leave that choice to parents.

Comment: To me, scholarship is the narrower term.  Teaching covers more than just the sharing of facts at the heart of scholarship.  Thomas and Marshall represent very different beliefs.  But they also shared a lot of culture that may not make sense to people that did not share those same experiences.

Comment: It's a bit of a chicken/egg thing with teachers/scholars.  In my view the egg came first, (presumably occurring by various complimentary naturally selected mutations), and here the egg would correspond to our first scholars.

Comment: @Brythan Negro and Nigger are two different words. Nigger does not appear at the original answer. English is an equivocal language. People are free to invent and redefine words to suit their interests at any time. There are hundreds of years of case law and literature which includes the term Negro; Negroes still use the word today. It is not clear who decided one day to arbitrarily declare the word Negro a "racial slur" other than the moderator who deleted the valid answer. Is it forbidden to challenge and refute western academia and those who drink from that fount exclusively at Politics SE?

Comment: They are two different words.  But modernly, some people treat them in a more similar fashion.  And you still haven't explained why that word was required rather than alternatives like "black" or "African-American".  I personally don't have a strong opinion on banning that particular word.  There are alternatives.  You can still challenge and refute western academia and those who exclusively drink from that fount without using that word.

Comment: @guest271314  The greater problem is that when confronted, you chose a bad method of debate.  Instead of altering the answer to respond to complaints, you simply reposted the original answer with an additional, even more hostile paragraph.  Philipp apparently responded to a flag by doing what the flagger wanted:  deleting the answer.  That is an arguable response.  The way that one argues moderation decisions here is to post in Meta with an explanation of why you feel that it is appropriate.

Comment: It's impossible to say what the Meta response would have been.  I would have likely posted an answer suggesting that you could replace the arguably offensive word with another but supporting leaving the offending phrase.  Others may or may not have agreed with that.  I say this as someone who has had two or three of what I would consider my best answers voted into oblivion because they didn't comply with groupthink.

Comment: Brythan, quite apart from the matter of this specific question (where, ironically, I basically agree they shouldn't have been deleted), have you read some of the other stuff they've been saying? It might help you see where they're coming from.

Answer (score 2):

The Stack exchange policy is not **No Slurs**,
it is **Be Nice**.

Obviously, all use of slurs is unnice.
But many things that are not slurs are also unnice.
There is no need to debate exactly whether an unnice thing was a slur or not,
because it is already unnice.

Comment: Unfortunately that's no answer at all for those of us that feel *guest271314*'s answer was and is, (in its author's own verbose and passionate manner), both nice and free of slurs.  Evidently others find misreading-based censorship to be much nicer still...