# What is the rationale for the "question ban" for user guest271314?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

> **You have reached your question limit**
>
> Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the [Help Center](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) to
>   learn more.

> **How can I get out of a question ban?**
>
> Begin by **improving** [your existing questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21216/guest271314?tab=questions): do as much as possible to make them clear, specific and on-topic.
>
> The ban will be lifted automatically by the system when it determines
>   that your positive contributions outweigh the cost of those questions
>   which were poorly received.
>
> **Stack Exchange cannot lift question bans by request.**
>
> **Edit** [*all* of your questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21216/guest271314?tab=questions), paying special attention to those that score 0 or less. All questions are expected to be useful to
>   future visitors, so put effort into writing with proper grammar and
>   spelling, formatting your post so it can be read easily, and providing
>   as much detail as possible about your problem and what you have
>   already tried. Then write a title that summarizes your problem so that
>   others encountering the exact same issue can find it. Reading your
>   question out loud to yourself can help you understand what it sounds
>   like to others.

What is the rationale for the question ban for user [guest271314](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/21216/guest271314)?

What specific actions need to be performed to lift the question ban?

Answer (score -18, accepted):

The Moderation Algorithm needs work.

If the ban is ridiculous or irrational The moderator should lift the ban.

If the moderator wants to lift the irrational ban, but cannot because of a feature, then that feature is buggy.

If the moderator wants to lift the ban, but cannot because of a bug, the bug should be fixed.

If the moderator refuses to work at getting a bug fixed, (["Not my job"](https://digitalsynopsis.com/buzz/not-my-job-funny-pics/)), the moderator should get another hobby and let someone else moderate who does work at getting bugs fixed.

Comment: But it's not really an irrational ban, is it? The user asked 10 questions, 6 of which have received a significant number of downvotes, and 8 of which are closed. The rationale of the algorithm is that if majority of a user's content is poorly received and needs to be closed or removed, then that user should probably stop posting content for a while. Sounds perfectly reasonable to me, and not a "bug" or "irrational".

Comment: @MartinTournoij, Yes, you're right.  On an algorithmic level, all resulting decisions are ineluctably *100%* rational, barring user input and random number generation.  What's irrational is the lazy rationale of blindly applying a banning algorithm designed for computer programming questions to a naturally far more contentious topic like politics in spite of the evidence here that *Politics.SE* breaks that algorithm.

Comment: I see no evidence that the algorithm is broken; your answer assumes that it is but does not explain why.

Comment: @MartinTournoij, The why is that the writings of *guest271314* deserve a lot more respect, and a lot less smarm.

Comment: [Comments archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82577/discussion-on-answer-by-agc-what-is-the-rationale-for-the-question-ban-for-use). The discussion was going in circles, in a rather unproductive and at points outright rude manner.

Answer (score 20):

This was an automatic question block made by the Stack Exchange algorithm. The details of the algorithm aren't public (we moderators don't know them either). But it usually seems to get triggered when most of the questions of a user got a negative voting scores. This includes questions which got deleted, apparently regardless of whether the question was deleted by the user, by a moderator or by delete-votes from the community. These are all the deleted questions by that user (posted with their permission):

- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31431 (-4, closed as "unclear what you're asking" by 5 users, then auto-deleted)
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31606 (-6, closed for "promotes or discredits a specific political cause" by 3 users and one mod, then auto-deleted)
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31797 (-8, closed as off-topic by 5 users, then auto-deleted)
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32157 (-11,closed by 3 users and a mod, deleted by the user)
- https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32206 (-6, deleted by me because it was a duplicate of the closed and self-deleted 32157)

In order to convince the algorithm to lift the block, follow the instructions in the help article you found.

For more information, please read the following questions on the general meta stackexchange:

- [Comprehensive question quality blocks now enabled everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291142/comprehensive-question-quality-blocks-now-enabled-everywhere)
- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: The links do not answer the question

Comment: @guest271314 I'm sorry, but this is all the help I am able to provide. As I said, the details of the algorithm are not known to me either and moderators are unable to lift automatic bans.

Comment: It is not clear precisely why the question ban was placed on the account nor what needs to be done to have the question ban removed. Can you migrate the question to meta stackexchange?

Comment: @guest271314 I don't see what that would accomplish. They would tell you the exact same thing and/or close this as a duplicate of some other complaint about a question block.

Comment: @guest271314 If you want some advise on improving a *specific* question you posted, please open a new question here on politics meta where you link to that specific question and ask for how it could be improved. Users with high reputation score can view deleted questions if you provide a direct link.

Comment: That is the problem. There is only 1 question by this user where the "score" is "0 or less" https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/21216. What is the purpose of editing deleted and closed questions? How does that make sense? Edited to what? To not ask about the so-called "white race"? Or to not ask about the political construct of "race" at all? Your answer is not clear whatsoever.

Comment: @guest271314 The user got 5 deleted questions with negative voting scores. 1 deleted by the user, 1 deleted by a moderator and 3 which got auto-deleted after they got closed and not edited for a month. Would it be OK if I post links to them?

Comment: Yes, post the links. **What specific actions need to be performed to lift the question ban?**

Comment: @guest271314 I added the links. When you would like to ask the community what changes would convince them to undelete these questions and upvote them (or at least remove their downvotes), then please open separate meta-questions for them.

Comment: @guest271314 - I'll grant that questions about race and racism are frequently unfairly downvoted. *However*, questions coming from an objective perspective are often better received than those promoting an agenda (for instance, apologetics for views associated with the Nation of Islam).

Comment: @Obie2.0 _"However, questions coming from an objective perspective are often better received than those promoting an agenda (for instance, apologetics for views associated with the Nation of Islam"_ Why do you continue to insert the topic of the Nation of Islam into discussions? You have been told that this user is not a member of that organization. You have also been told that from this users' perspective the Nation of Islam is not a "black supremacist" organization. There are no apologies associated with that perspective. It is based on facts, not belief. You cannot substantiate any "agenda"

Comment: @Philipp Moving forwards, not backwards. Am not interested in "convince the algorithm". There is no spook in the sky or ghost in the machine. Humans write the algorithm. And evidently change the would-be mysterious "algorithm" to satisfy their political interests. If this user cannot ask a question without being banned from asking questions, so be it. Will not alter approach to appease an "algorithm" or one or more humans.

Comment: @Obie2.0 There is a significant different between that question and this user's question. That question asks a simple question: "does the nation of Islam still hold black supremacist beliefs", whereas this user's questions are long, uses overly woolly phrasing, often seem to be making a point (rather than just asking a question), and the questions it asks are often confusing and/or unanswerable. It has little to do with the topics it covers.

Comment: @MartinTournoij _"whereas this user's questions are long, uses overly woolly phrasing, often seem to be making a point (rather than just asking a question), and the questions it asks are often confusing and/or unanswerable."_ Your feedback is welcome. However, your argument fails to recognize the possibility that a user other than _you_ does not interpret the questions the same as you, is not bothered by the question length, is not confused by and is capable of answering the question. You can stop reading if _you_ are confused by the question and move on instead of campaigning for closure.

Comment: `You can stop reading if you are confused by the question and move on instead of campaigning for closure` I'm not "campaigning" for anything @guest271314; I merely cast one close vote. You need five people to close a question, it's entirely possible that the fault is mine is misunderstanding your question, but if several people come to the same conclusion as me, then the problem is *probably* with your question, and not the five people.

Comment: @MartinTournoij The point is there is a possibility that a user understands the question, does not view the content as a "problem" and is capable of answering the question, notwithstanding one or more users' decision not to or inability to answer the question. "down" vote as much as you want, but vote to "close"  deprives other users' who do understand - even if only one exists - the question from answering the question.

Comment: @guest271314 Of course there is the possibility that **a** user finds it useful. But that's not how communities work. I don't want to dig through a pile of bad questions to find the good ones. *That* is why poor questions or questions that don't fit this platform are closed and removed. Asking questions is a privilege, not a right.

Comment: @MartinTournoij, Re *"privilege"*:  Any true *"privilege"* should be possible to revoke universally, and still keep *SE* going, but that can't work anymore than an apiary can profit without bees.   Rather it's contractual, (a user agreement), and a [business model](https://equityzen.com/trending/stackexchange/).  Sell job listings, ads, metadata, and eyeballs with user questions as the honey.  It's a question of what makes the best honey: worshipping a dumb machine as [smarter than us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skynet_(Terminator)), or cautiously using machines as fallible tools.

Comment: @MartinTournoij, [Ignoring the dissent of the sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horton_Hears_a_Who!) is certainly how dysfunctional communities work.  Nobody else wants to dig though bad questions either, but pretending a programmer's algorithm is a bug-free match for politics is the way to *increase* the number of bad questions and useless answers.  Bugs matter.

Comment: @agc It is abundantly clear that the "algorithm" was written or modified to target this user. There is no "community", there is a pseudo clique of would-be SE operatives incapable of gathering concepts outside of their soft core comfort zone. When SE wants to fly their flag they do so and the "algorithm" does not stop that internal propaganda from being published _"After all the mess caused by changing the logo just because Joel is homosexual, I thought the team would have learned the lesson that it's better to avoid political matters on Stack Overflow"_ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342940

Comment: @guest271314, Not impossible, but I've hunted software bugs for decades, and suppose it more probable that it's yet another stupid bug, abetted some overly defensive bureaucracy -- unfortunately that's not necessarily a hazard level downgrade.  At worst a very defensive bureaucracy would rather die than be made self-aware of some random trivial fault, if they're somehow institutionally invested in obliviousness.  A sort of *Mean Girls* culture sometimes, (not all the time, or nothing would ever get done), haunts the supposedly logical lives of programmers, mathematicians and academics.

Comment: @agc There are other examples of both negligence, denial of negligence and censorship when the negligence is pointed out [A Post-Mortem on the Recent Developer Story Information Leak](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/340960) (answer deleted; etc.); [adzerk serving ads from adsafeprotected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/335956)

Comment: Can you please try to stay on-topic? Whatever happens on meta.stackoverflow.com isn't relevant for this website.

Comment: @guest271314 if there are really people that don't believe that your question should be closed, there are reopen votes. If you get 5 reopen votes then the question will get reopened. If the question is helpful, it would get reopened. The algorithm isn't targeting you. The majority of your questions were deemed unhelpful by the community so the algorithm banned you.