# How often does the automatic question ban happen?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

## How often does the automatic question ban happen?

I read through the [answer](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3507/20623) to this [question about "question bans"](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-question-ban-for-user-guest271314) and it seemed to me that the automatic algorithm could be gamed by a group of 5 to 10 users serial downvoting/vote to closing on a user to trigger an automatic question ban.

I don't know the specifics of that case and am not trying to argue them but the numbers of downvotes/VtC's would easily be obtained by a small group of people intentionally targeting a specific user. I assume most users wouldn't be as vocal about defending themselves and was curious how often this automatic question ban happens?

Comment: [related](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/if-and-only-if-there-were-professional-trolls-and-moles-here-what-if-anythi?rq=1) about planned manipulation.

Comment: This kind of information isn't available to moderators, it'll take someone from SE to answer this.